# Default Left layered navigation missing in Fresh Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.

In my fresh magento i have a category called **Mens**.

in that category i have 2 test Products Created from Admin panel.

When i goto that category i found it is missing Layered Navigation Bar.

Its showing like this.

[image]

How i can make it as working.

Any Ideas ?

Thanks...

Comment: did you set category as anchored ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `is anchor` option to `yes` in admin side. Then only the `layered navigation` will be available for the category page.